# When using OpenID login within an iOS app is it better to use Safari for login and then redirect back to app?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, openid

I'm building an app that uses OpenID for authentication. I'm giving Google, Yahoo and the general OpenID site as options.

At present, when the user selects a site, I open a UIWebView and the user performs their login with that frame, all within the app.

However, it has struck me that when using UIWebView, you cannot easily show to the user that the connection is over https or that they are indeed at the site I'm claiming they are at. I could be easily harvesting passwords.

Would it be, and I'm looking for opinions on this, be better from a user confidence perspective to actually open Safari when the user selects a login and once they've logged in have Safari direct me back to app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just my 2 cents, it would be also faster if the user has already logged in those services with Safari before.

Prompting out a UIWebView and switching to Safari is using the same amount of steps, so why not?

Comment: Yes, I found that too. If the user has already logged into Google Reader etc. the can quickly move through the login process. The code is actually much cleaner too. I was just curious as to whether users prefer staying in one app and having no idea if they are being spoofed other a quick in-and-out transition.

Comment: I think users would not be confused, if I have an OpenID/Google I'd be glad that I can login directly. Even switching to Safari would not be confusing, since I see the login page of Google and it will ask my permission for your app, you may tell the user you will switch to Safari after clicking the login button with a UIAlertView.

Comment: And any user has played with Facebook login before should know why app switches when he clicked the login button

Comment: That's a good point about telling them what's going to happen. I might put some help text on the login page.

Answer (score 2):

Most people using iOS devices are used to the way Facebook logins work; no URL bar, no nothing. I'd just follow the typical workflow. You could bump out to Safari, and return via a custom URL scheme. However, I think users will think that is more weird. iOS users are not used to being jumped in and out of different apps.

Comment: That's true in Facebook's case, but that's because it's a single login. When you want to use Facebook login in other apps, you'll either open Safari or the Facebook app.

Comment: I've definitely used apps where a modal view appears to access Facebook. I dont whether this is outdated practice though.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd follow up on this thread to say I'm having difficulties getting the app approved and I think it's because I use the Safari approach. I've had it rejected by Apple twice now because:

"Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected "

I think it's because I'm launching Safari. I've opened a dispute with Apple and I'll come back with more information once I hear back from them. I really hope a quick change to a UIWebView will help!

Comment: After a lot of submissions, it turns out my app was rejected for a different reason. This mechanism is accepted by Apple.